# How to set data format in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

There is a way to change the date format of a column db?

In my case i only added a column "birthday" to default User from standard new project --auth, but displaying data i naturally get format of database data that i want to change to "d-m-Y".

User model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'firstname','lastname', 'email', 'password',
];


/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];

protected $dates = [
    'birthday',
];
```

}

dashboard.blade:

```
<article class="image-box style2 box innerstyle personal-details">


                                        <!--<a href="#" class="button btn-mini pull-right edit-profile-btn">{{__('home.ProfileEdit')}}</a>-->
                                        <h2 class="box-title fullname">{{ Auth::user()->lastname }}{{ Auth::user()->firstname }}</h2>
                                        <dl class="term-description">                                                
                                            <dt>{{__('home.FirstName')}}:</dt><dd>{{ Auth::user()->firstname }}</dd>
                                            <dt>{{__('home.LastName')}}:</dt><dd>{{ Auth::user()->lastname }}</dd>
                                            <dt>{{__('home.Birthday')}}:</dt><dd>{{ Auth::user()->birthday ?? '' }}</dd>
                                            <dt>{{__('home.Gender')}}:</dt><dd>{{ Auth::user()->gender }}</dd>
                                            <dt>{{__('home.EmailAddress')}}:</dt><dd>{{ Auth::user()->email }}</dd>
                                            <!--<dt>E-mail:</dt><dd>{{ Auth::user()->created_at }}</dd>-->
                                        </dl>

                                </article>
```

There is a way to change format without use

```
<dt>{{__('home.Birthday')}}:</dt><dd>{{ Auth::user()->birthday->format('d.m.Y') }}
```

in blade.view?

Comment: You can cast the birthday date attributte like this `protected $casts = [
    'birthday'  => 'date:d.m.Y',
];`.

Comment: If you only want to format the output, why not do that? That's common practise

Comment: @NicoHaase I have problems when the user has not yet set "birthday" date, which could changed from the profile page but it is not mandatory on the base registration, so {{ Auth::user()->birthday->format('d.m.Y') ?? ' ' }} dont' work

Answer (score 0):

You can define a mutator for the `birthday` attribute on the model.

```
public function getBirthdayAttribute($value)
{
    return $value->format('d.m.Y');
}
```

Now, when you call `$user->birthday`, it will always return a string in the format of `d.m.Y`.

Comment: For some strange reason this doesn't wok, rly no have idea what's the problem :(

Comment: The function name needs to be `getBirthdayAttribute`

Comment: Oh shoot, I was too fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I close the question by posting the code that I used and that seems to work.

in my model :

```
public function getBirthdayAttribute($value)
{

    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-m-Y');

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hedam is on the right track, but to define an accessor, the function name needs to be of the form `getFieldAttribute`. Example:

```
public function getBirthdayAttribute($value)
{
    return $value->format('d.m.Y');
}
```

Does that work?

More info about defining an Eloquent accessor: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: This should be the right way, but getting "Call to a member function format() on string" error

Comment: Anyway work with carbon:parse , is the right way to handle date in your opinion?